# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined (Help Me)

Tags: reactjs, select

Why Map Can't Read Property....

```
<select  className="inputData inputDiv">
    {dataKota.map((KotaPrint, KotaKey) =>
        <option key={KotaKey} value={KotaPrint.id_kota}>{KotaPrint.kota}</option>
    )}
</select>
```

This Error [image]

Comment: `dataKota` is on the state of the Component or you defined it on other place? Are you shure that is an iterable object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataKota` is `undefined` at some point, and undefined has no `map` prop/method. If you're loading an array into `dataKota` asynchronously, you may want to use a short-circuit evaluation to make sure you have a value.

```
<select className="inputData inputDiv">
    {dataKota && dataKota.map((KotaPrint, KotaKey) =>
        <option key={KotaKey} value={KotaPrint.id_kota}>{KotaPrint.kota}</option>
    )}
</select>
```